# BIRT report with web service data source throwing exception Unable to open connection. org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.OdaException

Tags: apache, tomcat, birt

I am trying to user web service as a datasource for BIRT report.
Report run well in Eclipse but from the webviewer deployed in tomcat it doesn't.

BIRT version : 4.2.1
Tomcat: 6

Below is the exception I am getting.

```
Dec 6, 2012 3:00:01 PM org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.odaconsumer.ConnectionManager openConnection
SEVERE: Unable to open connection.
org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.OdaException
    at org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.oda.ws.impl.Connection.open(Connection.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.consumer.helper.OdaConnection.open(OdaConnection.java:250)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.odaconsumer.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:165)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.executor.DataSource.newConnection(DataSource.java:224)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.executor.DataSource.open(DataSource.java:212)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.DataSourceRuntime.openOdiDataSource(DataSourceRuntime.java:217)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.QueryExecutor.openDataSource(QueryExecutor.java:407)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.QueryExecutor.prepareExecution(QueryExecutor.java:317)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a "Caused by:" in the stack trace?

As a wild guess, this is a network/firewall problem. I assume that he Tomcat server is running on a different machine and/or with a different OS account than your Eclipse IDE.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue, Some one can check the url ,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28578243/how-to-assign-the-birt-report-rptdesign-file-to-jsp