# How to assign the birt report rptdesign file to jsp

Tags: jsp, birt

I am completely new about BIRT Report.
The report content's fetching the data from MySQL DB then generated '**.rptdesign**' file. I am able to generate '*.rptdesign*' file. Now I need to use '*.rptdesign*' file in JSP file. 
How to configure the '*.rptdesign*' in JSP and how to display report in JSP file.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the BIRT runtime setup on a server somewhere you could use an iFrame to render the report within a JSP.

```
<iframe name="myReport" src="http://localhost:8080/birt/run?__report=test.rptdesign&amp;sample=my+parameter" />
```

If you don't have the BIRT runtime setup yet, [this](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2014/12/deploy-birt-viewer-for-tomcat/) is a recent blog explaining steps you could take to get it set up.

Hope this helps

Comment: I have resolved the issue and it came with error 'org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.odaexception unable to find the connection profile'. Reference is http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseBIRT/article.html and it is working  in eclipse but not in tomcat server

Comment: @Prathyush Are you using a connection profile to connect the dataset to your database or just a direct jdbc connection?  Is a JDBC driver installed on the server? [This](http://developer.actuate.com/community/forum/index.php?/topic/24140-birt-viewer-in-tomcat-unable-to-open-connection/) discussion seems similar to your situation although it was dealing with an Oracle connection. Connection profile help for you may be [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Birt_3.7_Migration_Guide#Connection_Profiles)

Comment: Yes u r correct I set the path in connection profile in catelina.bat from WINDOWS. I deployed the same in Ubuntu server It came with bug.In Ubuntu where to set the connection profile path.